# wicket-rest does not work with wicket 1.5

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

The [wicket-rest](http://code.google.com/p/wicket-rest) project which has now been forked to [github](https://github.com/wicketstuff/sandbox/tree/master/wicket-rest) does not work with wicket-1.5.

This problem has been raised in the [wicket mailing list](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/wicket-rest-and-Wicket-1-5-RC4-2-MarkupNotFoundException-Can-not-determine-Markup-td3600779.html#a3602317) but has remained unresolved. I tried out the suggestions given in the mailing list but the problem persists. The "onBeforeRender" method is not invoked and thus the wicket-rest pre-processing is effectively bypassed.

May be "onBeforeRender" is not invoked when stateless hint is set to true?

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I managed to solve this problem and thought of sharing this with the community.

Because of api changes in wicket-1.5, the following changes are needed in the wicket-rest-api classes:

- AbstractWebServicePage (or it's equivalent if you have forked it) should now implement IMarkupResourceStreamProvider. The implementation can be like this: (taken from the mailing list)

  ```java
  @Override
  public IResourceStream getMarkupResourceStream(MarkupContainer container, Class<?> containerClass)
  {
      return new StringResourceStream("");
  }
  ```
- "hasAssociatedMarkup" is now deprecated and can be removed from AbstractWebServicePage.
- Move the code defined inside the overridden "onBeforeRender" in AbstractWebServicePage to a method named "onBeforeRenderPage". Please note that this method is not part of wicket api but created by us as the "onBeforeRender" is somehow not invoked in this case.

  ```java
  protected void onBeforeRenderPage()
  {
      HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) getRequest().getContainerRequest();
      HttpServletResponse servletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) getResponse().getContainerResponse();

      String method = servletRequest.getMethod();
      logger.debug("Received a {} request from {}:{}", new Object[]{method, servletRequest.getRemoteAddr(),
              servletRequest.getRemotePort()});

      if (POST.equals(method)) {
          try {
              setModelFromBody(getRequestBody());
          } catch (Exception e) {
              //swallow this exception
          }
          doPost(getPageParameters(), servletRequest, servletResponse);
      } else if (GET.equals(method)) {
          doGet(getPageParameters(), servletRequest, servletResponse);
      }
  }
  ```
- In the respective subclass (JSon, Xml etc), replace the method "onRender()" with "renderPage()" and invoke our custom written super method "onBeforeRenderPage" before doing anything else. It might look like this:

  ```java
  @Override
  public final void renderPage()
  {
      super.onBeforeRenderPage();
      getResponse().write(getJson());
  }
  ```

That's it, you are now ready to enjoy the elegant wicket-rest api once again, this time with wicket-1.5.

I have tested this and using it.

If you have a better opinion, please share it.